# Button created in RowDatabound doesn't fire click event

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am adding LinkButton in gridview RowDataBound event and here i am also firing the click event on

```
        protected void cgvProjectPropertyList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        LinkButton lnkDelete = new LinkButton();
        lnkDelete.Text = "Delete";
        e.Row.Cells[COL_INDEX_DELETE].Controls.Add(lnkDelete);
        lnkDelete.CommandName = "Delete";

        lnkDelete.Click += new EventHandler(lnkDelete_Click);
    }
}

void lnkDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

lnkDelete_Click event is not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the fact that you are adding the `LinkButton` control dynamically, which is a pretty painful approach in ASP.NET WebForms.

In order for events in ASP.NET to work the control has to be there after the Load event, because that's when control events are fired. Otherwise there isn't any `Linkbutton` to bind the click event to.

My suggestion is that you try to add the `LinkButton` in the markup instead. It will save you a lot of pain. Then you can use the `RowCommand` on the `GridView` instead.

If that isn't an option, you have to add the the Linkbutton in the Load event and register a handler for its click event there.

I have a [post](http://devva.net/blog/post/Nested-ListViews-with-DataPager-and-custom-data-source.aspx) that is using `ListView`, which is using this approach. You should be able to learn from that.

Comment: That's the best way to do it, if you have the option to do so. Also, have look att the ASP.NET Page Lifecycle. If you understand that, you will be more productive in ASP.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try putting a `public` in front of `void lnkDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

that sometimes makes some problems

Comment: I have tried and it doesn't worked. This is not the issue because code is in same class.

Comment: ok then i don't know, but you could add the button in markup and then hide it where it is not need or supposed to be there

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RowCommand` instead, like..

```
 protected void cgvProjectPropertyList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
      e.CommandArgument // will Return current Row primary key value, rather row Index
    }
}
```

and you need to make sure to register the event in the GridView `OnRowCommand="cgvProjectPropertyList_RowCommand"`

Comment: You need to add OnRowCommand="cgvProjectPropertyList_RowCommand" to your gridview

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding the LinkButtons in RowDataBound event of gridview. but when the page is postback on click of link button, they haven't been re-created, so there is nothing for the page to bind the click events to. You will need to create them again in the PreRender event if it's a postback. So you will probably also need to store some of the information you used to determine how to create the LinkButtons in ViewState, so that you can re-create them in PreRender. Once you do this, the controls will be available to the page to bind the events to, and your handler will get called.